# Binding a ComboBox to dataset but read the dispay value from other source

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a `DataSet`, where in the first table and in the row i got a column called `OrderStatus`.

This field is a `number between 0 and 3`. What I want to achieve is when the data is loaded, I want to see the `clear text of the`OrderStatus`in the`ComboBox` on my windows form.

> Status 0 = Order in progress, 1 = Order is packaged, 2 = order
>   complete etc.

I have not found a way of binding the combobox and use a list of values to display the status in clear text.

Also when iIchange the status with the combo box I want it to reflect back to the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the  `DisplayMember and ValueMember property` of the [combo box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox_properties).

The **[DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember)** of a Combobox gets or sets a string that specifies the property of the data source whose contents you want to display. Here you want `Order In Progress`, `Order is packaged` etc..

The **[ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember)** property determines which value gets moved into the SelectedValue of the Combo Box. here you will set the corresponding ID values i.e. 0, 1, or 2 in your case

So, `OnSelectionChanged` you can get the SelectedValue i.e. 0, 1 or 2 which you bind earlier and update back the DataSet.